# "Alert when I need to leave" reminds me 15 minutes too early. How can I turn that off?

Tags: macos, ios, calendar, ical, reminders

Say I create an event starting at **2 pm** and at a location that takes me **10 min** to walk to. I also add the alert `Time to leave` as the only alert.

Then, I will get a reminder at **1:35 pm**. But I want the reminder only at **1:50 pm**, exactly "when I need to leave" (without setting the reminder manually to 1:50 pm, of course).

How can I achieve this?

I know that I can snooze the notification, which will make it reappear in 15 minutes. But, then I am distracted from whatever I'm doing 15 minutes too early. So it is not a solution.

**Edit:** I want the event to still be displayed as starting at **2 pm** in my calendar.

**Edit 2:** Also assume that I do not know the travel time when I create the event. So the mechanism of `Time to leave` that adjusts flexible to my location is still necessary.

Comment: In apple maps how long does it say the route takes?

Comment: The 10 minutes in the example are computed by the Calendar application using Apple maps. For example the Calendar iOS notification reads *It will take 10 minutes to get to [address]* and in the top right it reads *in 25m*.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the answer,

1. > When you create the event, make sure that you enter the location of the meeting in the event. Like in image, where you can see the greyed out portion with a caption

[image]
 2.

> Add Location (let it get recognize the event through the map app in
>   the background -- you do not have to do anything, this will happen
>   automatically based on your internet speed, so just give it some time,
>   and once you the location listed, select the desired location from the
>   options or the nearby location.)

3.

> Once you do that, if you try to set your event time say
>   08:00PM-09:00PM.  Automatically you calendar will recognize this event
>   as a remote location and will prompt you differently like this,

[image: Time to Leave]

This will update you about the meeting at the right time accounting for your traffic and weather conditions.

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

When creating an event, there is the Alert option where it can be set to one of several options including "none"...

However, based on your comment, just add 15mins to the leave time then it will alert you at the correct moment...

[image]

Comment: This seems to completely turn off the reminder. But I *do* want to be reminded when it's time to leave.

Comment: The question in the title is clear, what you really want is something else then... Confusing... Please edit your question.

Comment: What part of the question in the title is different from what I want?

Comment: The title asks to "turn that **off**" ... which was answered...

Comment: The question asks to turn off the "too early" reminder. Not all reminders. Hence it was not answered.

Comment: Read the edited addition to the answer...

Comment: Thanks, this does answer my question as posted. I will edit it now to include the constraint, that I want the calendar start time to reflect true start time. When someone asks me "When are meeting for lunch?" I want to be able to look at the calendar and read it out without first checking if this event has an "Alert me when to leave" reminder and only in that case subtracting 15 minutes from it.

Answer (score 0):

Manually enter the desired travel time in the appointment. This overrides the calculated time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this requires me to know the travel time at time of event creation, and thereby would take away the whole benefit of the automatically location adjusting "when I need to leave". Hence, it's not a solution, but I have edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: One of the problems is that the calculated time will never exactly line up with the actual time because digital routing still doesn’t exactly match real-world travel time.

Comment: Are you saying the reason Apple implemented a too early reminder is because it is a very risk-averse solution to take care of the uncertainties of actual vs. planned travel time?

Comment: Only Apple knows. I’d guess it’s simply inaccuracy with the current data and technology we have.

Comment: The iOS notification specifically displays *both*  `in 25m` at the top corner and `It will take 10m to get there` in the body. So the data is there and relatively accurate. Even if the predicted and actual time are different, why would Apple not notify me correctly at the time I need to leave according to their estimates?

Comment: That actually looks like a duplicate notification, not related to travel time

Comment: And where would that duplicate notification come from?

Comment: Not sure, I'd think one is from the Calendar itself and the other one might be from Siri Suggestions?